# Get the error message passed to mongoose middleware next() method to client controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN stack so please pardon my naive question but I've not been able to figure out how to pass a custom error message from my Mongoose pre-save hook middleware to my Angularjs controller.
I'm using a pre-save hook to check if a document have been saved before. If it has, then I want to cancel the saving attempt and rather update the document. I used the `next(new Error('Error message'))` method to prevent the `save` action. Below is my code:
**At my back-end:**

```
VoteSchema.pre('save',function(next){
  var self = this;
  self.constructor.findOneAndUpdate(
    {'choice._id':self.choice._id},
    {$inc:{'choice.count':1}},
    {new:true},
    function(err,doc){
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(doc!==null){

        //I want to be able to pass a type like this {x:1, y:2}
        //to my angular controller from here. How do I do this?

        return next(new Error("Canceled save attempt!")); //this cancels the save
      } 
      return next();
    });
});
```

**At my client controller:**

```
vote.$save(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (errorResponse) {

      //I want to get my custom type from the pre-save 
      //middleware hook here which was equals to {x:1, y:2}
      //or at least the message "Canceled save attempt!"
      //Note that I checked the 'errorResponse' object but
      //it isn't anywhere there

      console.log(errorResponse);
    }
  );
```

In other words, how can I pass a custom object from mongoose middleware (pre-save hook) to an Angular controller?

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing in my project, I have created an error.js file and also created many possible errors, And when it is required to send I simply require my error.js and send error like below code:

**error.js:**

```
var errors = {};
var util = require('util');

/**
 * Used to create errors
 * @Param {Number} httpCode - http response code
 * @Param {String} message - Error message
 */
function ApiError(httpCode, httpMessage, description) {
    this.httpCode = httpCode;
    this.httpMessage = httpMessage;
    this.description = description;
    this.details = null;
}

// inherit the Error class
util.inherits(ApiError, Error);

// exporting error Object
module.exports = errors;

errors.ApiError = ApiError;

/**
 * Sends httpCode and message to user
 * @Param {Response} res - http response
 */
ApiError.prototype.send = function (res) {
    res.status(this.httpCode);
    res.json({ httpCode: this.httpCode, httpMessage: this.httpMessage, description: this.description, details: this.details })
}

ApiError.prototype.withDetails = function (details) {
    this.details = details;
    return this;
};

errors.not_registeration = new ApiError(404, 'NOT_REGISTERATION',
    'User not registered with this email/mobile.');


errors.invalid_login = new ApiError(400, 'INVALID_LOGIN',
    'Login credentials do not match any registered user.');
```

You can create your own errors with codes here like i have already created.

**How to use errors in my file:**

```
var errors = require('../../library/errors');
.....
.....
.....
VoteSchema.pre('save',function(next){
  var self = this;
  self.constructor.findOneAndUpdate(
    {'choice._id':self.choice._id},
    {$inc:{'choice.count':1}},
    {new:true},
    function(err,doc){
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(doc!==null){

        return next(errors.not_registeration)  // Here  i am sending errors.
        or
        return next(errors.invalid_input.withDetails("This  is extra details"));

      } 
      return next();
    });
});
```

**Response would be every time:**

**If return next(errors.not_registeration)-**

```
 {
        "httpCode": 404,
        "httpMessage": "NOT_REGISTERATION",
        "description": "User not registered with this email/mobile.",
        "details": null
    }
```

**If return next(errors.invalid_input.withDetails("This  is extra details"))-**

```
{
    "httpCode": 400,
    "httpMessage": "INVALID_INPUT",
    "description": "The request input is not as expected by API. Please provide valid input.",
    "details": "This  is extra details"
}
```

** **As I understand you want to pass data to next middleware.**
Then you can do this in current middleware:

```
 res.locals.result={ X:1,Y:1};
```

In the next middleware you would be able to get X,Y like that: `console.log(res.locals.result);`
You can pass anything in next middleware by using `res.locals`.

Comment: I don't get any of the error messages passed to the `next()` function in my client controller

Comment: to do what you want, you should use res.locals.result={ X:1,Y:1}, In the next middleware you would be able to get X,Y. in the next middleware console.log(res.locals.result);

Comment: I have also updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know whether it is helpful or not.

Comment: No. Am interested in passing data from the middleware to my **client controller** not to another middleware

Comment: then you should use   " return  res.send({X:1,Y:1});  "  or " return res.json({X:1,Y:1});"

Comment: where do I get the `res` object in my middleware?

Comment: "res" comes from client request which is http response.   click here : http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148998/discussion-between-ochi-fortune-and-shubham-verma).